# If the child is position:absolute and the parent is overflow:hidden, why does the child overflow?

Tags: html, css

If the child is `position:absolute`, the parent is `overflow:hidden`, and the parent is `position:static`, the child still overflows:

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:100px;border:2px solid red;">
  <div style="position:absolute;height:200px;width:200px;background:blue;opacity:0.5">
  </div>
</div>
```

If the parent has a position other than `static`, the child no longer overflows:

```html
<div style="overflow:hidden;height:100px;border:2px solid red;position:relative;">
  <div style="position:absolute;height:200px;width:200px;background:blue;opacity:0.5">
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does this occur? What is this behavior called?

I'm using Chrome, is this behavior consistent across browsers?

Comment: it is consistent accross browsers, if absolute, an element will look for the closest parent (absolute or relative) and will use it as reference to draw itself inside it., if none found, it will use the window for reference and will come up front static elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the spec defines [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) as

> This property specifies whether content of a block container element
>   is clipped when it overflows the element's box. It affects the
>   clipping of all of the element's content except any descendant
>   elements (and their respective content and descendants) whose
>   containing block is the viewport or an ancestor of the element.

The absolutely positioned element is a descendant whose containing block is established by an ancestor of the element with `overflow: hidden`, as explained in [Definition of "containing block"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

> If the element has `position: absolute`, the containing block is
>   established by the nearest ancestor with a `position` of `absolute`,
>   `relative` or `fixed`

Therefore the absolutely positioned element is not affected by that `overflow: hidden`.

If the parent were positioned, it would be the containing block of the absolutely positioned element, and then `overflow: hidden` would affect it.

Comment: This doesn't work for `body` element. I set `overflow-x: hidden` and `position: relative`.
You can see the absolutely positioned element use `body` as positioning reference, but overflow still doesn't hide.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, take a close look at the MDN Documentation **[CSS Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)**.

So how does this relate to your question? let's first analyze `position: absolute`:

> absolute:
>   Do not leave space for the element. Instead, position it at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block. Absolutely positioned boxes can have margins, they do not collapse with any other margins.

As far as your case goes, the positioned ancestor `div` element does not have any specified `position` attribute to it.

Therefore, it assumes the default `position: static` which literally specifies nothing other than the standard position of the element in the page. Check it out:

> static:
>   This keyword lets the element use the normal behavior, that is it is laid out in its current position in the flow.  The top, right, bottom, left and z-index properties do not apply.

In other words, the child will not be positioned relative to its parent. The weird behavior is because you expect the parent `div` to be positioned when is not positioned at all. It falls to ask: what is the nearest positioned parent then? The answer is to go up on the DOM tree and find it, logically since you have nothing in your example but your two `div`, the nearest parent will be webpage document itself.

So, **how can you fix this?** By adding (for example) `position: relative` to the parent `div` element.

**EDIT: Overflow and Position properties**:

By using `overflow`, you are typically trying to do one (or all) of the following: clip content, render a scroll bar, display any overflown content in a particular way. I gather your goal however is to have the child `div` **not** overflow the parent `div`. The question of how to avoid this overflow can take you to a place you **[do not want to go](https://css-tricks.com/findingfixing-unintended-body-overflow/)**.

So by narrowing down *what* overflow is all about: (long story short) it is about controlling/modifying the look and feel of *the content of what is inside a particular HTML element*. Keep in mind, the content, not the element itself.

In your case, you may perceive the child element of your parent `div` as being the content of the parent `div`. Rather, what you actually see is the contents of the child element. The positioning of the parent and child with respect to each other is thus not controlled by the `overflow` property, but by the `position` property.

**Is this consistent across browsers?**:

Since CSS 2.1, the `overflow (visible | hidden | scroll | auto)` and `position (static | relative | absolute)` have been supported in all major browsers. Any discrepancies would occur when you extend on the `overflow` since certain of its attributes are not widely supported. See here for reference: **[Can I Use: Overflow](http://caniuse.com/#search=overflow)** (also scroll to the bottom for the CSS 2.1 reference).

Do you have any questions about this? Ask in the comments below.

Comment: I get that it's positioned relative to the closest non-static element, but I don't see why this should affect `overflow`s. Your answer does not mention `overflow` at all.

Comment: @Linksku I added to my answer to explain (as best as I can) how the *overflow* and *position* properties reflect in your case. FYI your question has been asked many times in Stack Overflow, but it made sense to me to explain what other answers have not. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you may be misunderstanding my question. I'm not concerned about how the divs are positioned, but about why they're overflowing. Oriol's answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Linksku fair enough, glad you found the answer you were looking for

Answer (score 1):

overflow property is not inherited anyhow: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

So in your first case it is understandable it is not working, since with static position the browsers put it in the order it reads and overlooks collisions.

In your second case absolute positioning actually sets a space for the container div and then puts the second div into it - thus makes the overflow hidden.

You can imagine it this way: in your first case you created two divs which are not related to each other but positioned on each other in the second case you created a container and forced another div into it by setting the container's overflow to hidden.

Hope it helped easy understanding,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

The relative value for the position property is very similar to that of the static value. The primary difference is that the relative value accepts the box offset properties top, right, bottom, and left. These box offset properties allow the element to be precisely positioned, shifting the element from its default position in any direction